# is there a way to force event to fire only once on given element (per element, not whole document) when using live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('div.myclass').live('click',function() {
    alert('i should respond only once');
});
```

I know that there is a `one()` function with jquery but i can't figure how to integrate this with the code above.

Comment: Is that once for each element, or once for the whole document?

Comment: It would be better to have a short significant title and put the question where it belongs ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('div.myclass').live('click',function() {
   if($(this).attr('clicked') != 'yes')
   {
    alert('i should respond only once');
    $(this).attr('clicked', 'yes');
   }

});
```

Comment: +1 Though this would be **far** better if you did `$(this).data('clicked', true)` and `if ($(this).data('clicked')) {` rather than using arbitrary textual attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In the `live()` click handler, you can `bind()` an event directly on the element which calls `e.stopPropagation()`. So on the next click, the event won't be able to bubble up to the document, where it actually triggers the live event.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kKHJm/

```
$('li').live('click',function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Do stuff once here
});
```