# .live disable double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a way to force event to fire only once on given element (per element, not whole document) when using live()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201242/is-there-a-way-to-force-event-to-fire-only-once-on-given-element-per-element-n)

This is my code:

```
$('.answerx').live('click', function(){
    comprobar($(this).attr('name') , "\'" + $(this).attr('id') + "\'");
})
```

I want to make it so that once the click has been made, the user is unable to click and run the function again as the function running more than once is making my program go crazy.

So is there a way to make it so that after clicking once it disables further clicks on specific element whose id is `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mark clicked object as such. There are many ways to do that. For example, add a class.

```
$('.answerx').live('click', function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    comprobar($(this).attr('name') , "\'" + $(this).attr('id') + "\'");
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
  }
})
```

Additional benefit of adding a class is that you can style disabled element respectively.

Comment: so no matter how many elements i have with .answerx, this will only be applied to that one which has been clicked on??

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, you should accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
var boolHasBeenRun = false;
$('.answerx').live('click', function(){
    if(boolHasBeenRun === false){
       comprobar($(this).attr('name') , "\'" + $(this).attr('id') + "\'");
       boolHasBeenRun = true;
    }

 });
```

Or

```
 $('.answerx').live('click', function(){
       comprobar($(this).attr('name') , "\'" + $(this).attr('id') + "\'");
        $('.answerx').die('click');        

 });
```

Or use the modern `.off()`

Comment: `unbind` won't work here. It only unbinds event handlers bound with `bind`.

Comment: And the problem with `die` is that it removes the event handlers for all the elements, not only for the clicked one.

Comment: Thats why I provided the first alternative.

Comment: That has the same effect, or do you have a `boolHasBeenRun` for each element? Once an element is clicked, the handler won't be executed for the others.

Comment: You are right, I was just thinking about the one element.

Comment: Hi, this wouldnt work i dont think because I have like 20 elements with .answerx and they all have differnt id's so I would need something that disables the click by id not by class or as you did it above thanks